# Using a member struct of a templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Is it possible to use the member `struct` or `enum class` of a templated class, without explicitly specifying the template arguments. So for ex:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo {
 public:
  enum class Status {E1, E2, E3};
};

void func() {
  auto e = Foo::Bar::E1;
}
```

I guess I see the point that the compiler needs to instantiate `Foo` given its template arguments, but just wondering if there is a way around to still use its member class.

Comment: Good question, but a duplicate, I'm afraid.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Fact is that `Foo<int, int>::Status` is not the same type than `Foo<void, void>::Status`.

Comment: Question Is why Is the enum a member type of the template class when IT does not depend on any of the template arguments? Actualy nothing in the class depend on template arguments, why Is the class a template one?

Comment: @slepic I just added a very minimal example to ask the question. There are other member variables in my real code, that depend on its template arguments.

Comment: Yes i thought it could be the case. But anyway the enum type does not depend on the template params, So maybe IT should Stand alone...

Answer (score 0):

If the type is not really important and you just want access to the enum class, maybe you can typedef it

```
using Bar = Foo<void, void>;

void func() {
  auto e = Bar::Status::E1;
}
```

I think your other option is to write the type explicitly or declare the enum class in namespace scope

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow use of a Template class without passing template parameters. However there is a workaround if your requirement is not restricted to two template parameters.

The workaround:
You can define the class Foo as variadic template. This will enable you to use the enum without passing parameters to the class Foo. Example is below:

```
template<typename ...A>
class Foo {
 public:
   using Bar = enum class Status {E1, E2, E3};
};

void func() {
  auto e = Foo<>::Bar::E1;
}
```

I am not sure if this will satisfy your requirement, but this will compile and work. I did compile it with c++17 flag.